# Where is the 2 minutes setting in the knoppix-halt file?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

According to the knoppix-halt file, it mention that

`Please remove CD, close cdrom drive and hit return [2 minutes]`

I look through the file so many times but still could not find the 2 minutes setting. I know that `sleep X` will sleep for X seconds while `usleep X` will sleep for microsecond. So, I went to look for `sleep 120` and `usleep 120000000` but did not find any.

So, can someone enlighten me why the message say 2 minutes but I could not find inside the script file?

```
    #!/bin/busybox sh
    # This script does:
    # - Kill all processes
    # - umount/sync filesystems (and freeing loopback files)
    # - Eventually eject CD-Rom (autoeject turned on)

    PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
    export PATH

    cd /

    NORMAL="\033[0;39m"
    RED="\033[1;31m"
    GREEN="\033[1;32m"
    YELLOW="\033[1;33m"
    BLUE="\033[1;34m"
    MAGENTA="\033[1;35m"
    CYAN="\033[1;36m"
    WHITE="\033[1;37m"
    GRAY="\033[1;38m"

    [ -r /etc/default/locale ] && . /etc/default/locale
    [ -r /etc/sysconfig/i18n ] && . /etc/sysconfig/i18n

    case "$LANG" in
     de*)
      EJECTMSG="Bitte CD entfernen, Laufwerk schließen und Eingabetaste drücken [2 Minuten]"
      COMPLETEMSG="Shutdown beendet."
      ;;
       *)
      EJECTMSG="Please remove CD, close cdrom drive and hit return [2 minutes]."
      COMPLETEMSG="Shutdown complete."
      ;;
    esac

    # Read in boot parameters
    read CMDLINE </proc/cmdline 2>/dev/null

    echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/printk
    PROGRESSBAR="/tmp/knoppix-halt.progress"
    progress(){
     local black="\033[0;0m \033[0m"
     local p
     local count=0
     echo -n -e "\033[1mSystem Shutdown...  \033[42;32m                                                       \033[0m"
     type usleep >/dev/null 2>&1 && sleep="usleep 100000" || sleep="sleep 1"
     [ -r "$PROGRESSBAR" ] && rm -f "$PROGRESSBAR" 2>/dev/null
     touch "$PROGRESSBAR"
     while [ -r "$PROGRESSBAR" ]; do
      if [ "$count" -ge 55 ]; then
       for p in "/" "-" "\\" "|"; do
        echo -n -e "\b${p}"
        $sleep
        [ -r "$PROGRESSBAR" ] || break
       done
      else
       echo -n -e "\b$black\b"
       $sleep
      fi
      let count++
     done
     echo -e "\r\033[J\033[1m${COMPLETEMSG}\033[0m"
    }

    # Return 0 if there is active swap, but
    # enough memory available to call swapoff, 1 otherwise.
    checkswap(){
     local free=0 buffers=0 cache=0 swaptotal=0 swapfree=0 info amount kb
     while read info amount kb; do
      case "$info" in 
        MemFree:)   free="$amount";;
        Buffers:)   buffers="$amount";;
        Cached:)    cached="$amount";;
        SwapTotal:) swaptotal="$amount";;
        SwapFree:)  swapfree="$amount";;
      esac
     done </proc/meminfo
     avail="$((free + buffers + cached))"
     swapused="$((swaptotal - swapfree))"
     if [ "$swaptotal" -gt 0 -a "$avail" -gt "$swapused" ] >/dev/null 2>&1; then
      return 0
     else
      return 1
     fi
    }

    OMIT=""
    for i in $(pidof ntfs-3g aufs aufsd fuse fuseblk cloop0 cloop1 cloop2 cloop3 cloop4 cloop5 cloop6 cloop7 klogd syslogd); do OMIT="$OMIT -o $i"; done 2>/dev/null
    killall5 -15 $OMIT; sleep 2

    case "$CMDLINE" in *nosound*|*noaudio*|*nostartsound*) true ;; *)
     # Play sound if soundcard is alive and soundfile present
     # (also giving running programs some more time to terminate)
     [ -r /usr/share/sounds/shutdown.ogg -a -f /proc/asound/pcm ] && \
       type -p ogg123 >/dev/null 2>&1 && \
        { ogg123 -q --audio-buffers 4096 /usr/share/sounds/shutdown.ogg 2>/dev/null & sleep 2; }
     ;;
    esac

    # Clean console i/o
    exec >/dev/console 2>&1 </dev/console
    stty sane
    echo -n -e "\r\033[K"

    # echo -e "\033[H\033[J"

    # Start progress bar
    [ -n "$DEBUG" ] || progress &

    # Check which device is mounted as /mnt-system
    system="$(awk '/ \/mnt-system /{print $1;exit 0}' /proc/mounts 2>/dev/null)"

    # noprompt or noeject option?
    NOPROMPT="yes"; NOEJECT="yes"
    case "$CMDLINE" in
     *noprompt*) ;;
     *) # Check if we need to wait for /mnt-system to be ejected.
      if [ -n "$system" ]; then
       for cdrom in $(awk '/drive name:/{print $NF}' /proc/sys/dev/cdrom*/info 2>/dev/null); do
        [ "$system" = "/dev/$cdrom" ] && { NOEJECT=""; NOPROMPT=""; break; }
       done
      fi
     ;;
    esac
    case "$CMDLINE" in *noeject*)  NOEJECT="yes"  ;; esac
    DEBUG=""
    case "$CMDLINE" in *\ debug\ *|*BOOT_IMAGE=debug*) DEBUG="yes" ;; esac

    # turn off swap, then unmount file systems.
    # should free ramdisk space first, check
    if checkswap; then
     swapoff -a >/dev/null 2>&1
    fi

    # Shut down network, if no nfs mounted
    # Actually... Not needed.
    # grep -q ' nfs' /proc/mounts || ifdown -a >/dev/null 2>&1

    # Kill remaining processes
    killall5 -9 $OMIT

    # Turn on autoeject of CD-Roms
    if [ -z "$NOEJECT" ]; then
     for dev in /proc/sys/dev/cdrom*/lock; do [ -f "$dev" ] && echo 0 > "$dev"; done
     for dev in /proc/sys/dev/cdrom*/autoeject; do [ -f "$dev" ] && echo 1 > "$dev"; done
    fi

    # Try to sync for 30 seconds max.
    sync &
    SYNCPID="$!"
    for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15; do
     sleep 2
     [ -d /proc/"$SYNCPID" ] || break
    done

    # Free modules
    # Do we need to unload modules at all?
    #
    #while read module relax; do
    # case "$module" in
    #  *eeepc*|*_laptop*) true ;; # Unloading eeepc_laptop disables WLAN in the BIOS. Why?
    #  *) rmmod "$module" ;;
    # esac
    #done </proc/modules >/dev/null 2>&1

    # Remove all automatically added entries from /etc/fstab
    sed -i -e "/^# Added by KNOPPIX/{N;d}" /etc/fstab

    # Force sync, then umount.
    tac /proc/mounts | while read d m f relax; do
     [ -d "$d" ] || continue
     case "$f" in tmpfs|proc|sysfs|devpts|usbfs|aufs) ;; *)
      case "$f" in rootfs|nfs*) ;; *) blockdev --flushbufs "$d" 2>/dev/null; umount -l "$m" 2>/dev/null ;; esac
      case "$d" in /dev/mapper/*) /sbin/dmsetup --force remove "$d" 2>/dev/null ;; esac
      ;;
     esac
    done

    # We have to use /bin/umount here, since busybox umount does not accept -t no*
    # /bin/umount -t notmpfs,noproc,nosysfs,nousbfs,norootfs,noaufs,nonfs -adrf 2>/dev/null

    # Free loopback devices which may have been used but not mounted.
    for i in /dev/loop* /dev/loop/*; do [ -b "$i" ] && losetup -d "$i" 2>/dev/null; done

    # End progress bar
    [ -f "$PROGRESSBAR" ] && { rm -f "$PROGRESSBAR" 2>/dev/null; sleep 1; }
    sleep 1
    echo ""

    # Mount boot medium read-only
    umount -r /mnt-system 2>/dev/null
    # And finally, umount
    umount -l /mnt-system 2>/dev/null
    # (Harddisk-installation only): mount / read-only
    umount -r / 2>/dev/null

    # Enable sysrq feature (just in case someone has turned it off)
    # echo -n -e '\033[s\033[8m' # No output, save cursor position
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
    echo s > /proc/sysrq-trigger 2>/dev/null & # emergency sync
    sleep 1
    echo u > /proc/sysrq-trigger 2>/dev/null & # emergency remount-ro
    sleep 1
    # echo -n -e '\033[28m\033[u' # re-enable output, restore cursor position

    # pre-load poweroff+halt+eject if not included in this shell
    poweroff --help >/dev/null 2>&1
    reboot --help   >/dev/null 2>&1
    eject --help   >/dev/null 2>&1

    if [ -z "$NOEJECT" ]; then
     ( eject -s $system >/dev/null 2>&1 || eject $system >/dev/null 2>&1 & )
     if [ -z "$NOPROMPT" ]; then
      echo -n -e "${CYAN}${EJECTMSG}${NORMAL} "
      read -t 120 a
     fi
    fi

    case "$0" in
     *halt|*poweroff) { poweroff -f 2>/dev/null & sleep 8; } || echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger 2>/dev/null ;;
     *)               { reboot -f   2>/dev/null & sleep 8; } || echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger 2>/dev/null ;;
    esac

    # Should never be reached.
    sleep 2
    echo -n -e "\033[1mYou can now turn off your computer.\033[0m"
    halt -f
    sleep 1337
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom it says:

```
echo -n -e "${CYAN}${EJECTMSG}${NORMAL} "
read -t 120 a
```

This writes the message, and then waits up to 120 seconds for you to press return.